# Why doesn't this code give any exceptions?

Tags: java, apache-commons

I am using Apache commons net library to upload a file to a server. This is the code:

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
        client.connect("");
        client.login("", "");
        client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
        client.storeFile("log", new FileInputStream("log"));
        client.logout();
    }
}
```

I haven't specified any url or login credentials. Why doesn't it give an exception?

Comment: Question - does the file actually get FTP'ed?  If so, your server must be allowing anonymous connections.

Comment: @DavidWallace Yes it gets FTP'ed to "". I haven't specified any url. What server are you talking about?

Comment: Oh, whoops, I missed that part!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the source code, you will notice

```
client.connect("");
```

ends up calling

```
InetAddress.getByName("")
```

which just returns

```
localhost/127.0.0.1
```

So if you have a service listening for connection on the default port 21 (to which the `FTPClient` connects) and doesn't require authentication, I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: Since the service running at port 0 is not FTP why doesn't storeFile() throw any exceptions?

Comment: The default FTP port is 21, not 0.  It's specified right there in FTPClient.

Comment: @DavidWallace Yup, sorry, I was looking at the parent class `SocketClient`. Thanks.